# Unused variables & Primary-Expression expected before ']'

Tags: c++, c++11

I looked at the other answers, but it didn't really help since 1) I don't understand it (especially if it's not exactly my problem) and 2) I noticed that the way my class is learning how to program is vastly different from what I've seen online. For example, we are using std. So I'm sorry for the repetitive question.

Here are my compiler errors:
    main.cc: In function ‘int sum_up(std::array)’:

```
main.cc:21:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
     sum+=arr[i,size_t];
               ^

main.cc:18:9: warning: unused variable ‘size’ [-Wunused-variable]
  size_t size = arr.size(); //A size_t is just an unsigned int on this system
         ^

main.cc: In function ‘int sum_up(std::vector<int>)’:

main.cc:28:9: warning: unused variable ‘size’ [-Wunused-variable]
  size_t size = vec.size();
         ^
```

Here's my code:
It was actually pre-made by our teacher; our main focus was the functions and how to sum up C style and C++ style arrays/vectors. I did my code exactly like my friend's but for some reason mine won't compile.

Please and thank you for all the help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const size_t ARR_SIZE = 5;

int sum_up(int arr[], size_t size) { //Function to sum up a C-style array
    int sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
        sum += arr[i];
    return sum; //Stub
}

int sum_up(array<int, ARR_SIZE> arr) {
    size_t size = arr.size(); //A size_t is just an unsigned in 
    //on       this system
    int sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
        sum += arr[i, size_t];

    return sum; //Stub 
}

int sum_up(vector<int> vec) {
      size_t size = vec.size();
      int sum = 0;
      for (size_t i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
          sum += vec[i];

      return sum; //Stub
}

void die() {
     cout << "Invalid input.\n";
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main() {
    int c_arr[ARR_SIZE] = {}; //Size ARR_SIZE, initialized to zero
    array<int, ARR_SIZE> cpp_arr = {}; //Size ARR_SIZE, initialized to zero
    vector<int> vec_arr(ARR_SIZE);  //Size ARR_SIZE, initialized to zero

    cout << "Welcome to the Arrayitizer 2000(tm). Today we will be doing    arrays three different ways.\n";
    cout << "Please enter " << ARR_SIZE << " integers.\n";

    //Now let's read into three arrays
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        if (!cin) die();
        c_arr[i] = x;
        cpp_arr[i] = x;
        vec_arr.at(i) = x;
    }

    //Let's print them out
    cout << "You entered (one column for each of the three arrays):\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        cout << c_arr[i] << "\t" << cpp_arr[i] << "\t" << vec_arr.at(i) << endl;
    }

    cout << "Summming up the three arrays:\n";

    //Now lets sum them up and verify they all return the same value
    int sum_c =   sum_up(c_arr, ARR_SIZE);
    int sum_cpp = sum_up(cpp_arr);
    int sum_vec = sum_up(vec_arr);

    cout << "sum_c:   " << sum_c   << endl;
    cout << "sum_cpp: " << sum_cpp << endl;
    cout << "sum_vec: " << sum_vec << endl;

    if (sum_c == sum_cpp and sum_c == sum_vec) {
        cout << "Congrats, you added up all three arrays the same!\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Unfortunately, your code for summing up the three arrays returned different results.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please fix your indentation?

Comment: Don't tag C++ questions [tag:c].

Comment: Of course, the right way to do this is `int sum_c = std::accumulate(std::begin(c_arr), std::end(c_arr), 0);` and the obvious variations for `cpp_arr` and `vec_arr`.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, the following is a typo:

```
arr[i,size_t]
//   ^^^^^^^
```

The compiler actually pointed you to exactly this code, so you could have spotted this. Or, at least, compared this part of the code with your friend's version (which cannot be "exactly like" yours if it compiles).

The warnings are just that: warnings. And they're warning you about what they say they're warning you about: variables that you declare but never use. So why declare them?

Finally, I don't understand why you say you're not "using std" — assuming you are not referring to the `using namespace` statement (because you *are* using that), I can only presume you think you're not using the standard library. Yet, you are! All over the place, in fact! Vectors, C++11 arrays, streams…

Comment: oops, sorry, i meant we are using STD! and most programs I've found arent. my bad

Comment: @Alexis: Sounds like you're finding a lot of terrible programs. Sadly that's quite easy in the C++ world as it has been around for so long and is generally taught so poorly.

Comment: the thing is, i dont understand how it is a typo? he put it that way is it supposed to be sum? and about declaring variables, i'm unsure. that's what the teacher put there and said to keep.

Comment: how can i declare them then? im not supposed to remove them. please and thank you

Comment: @Alexis: Well, typo or not, either way it's flat-out wrong. You got it right elsewhere: `arr[i]`. How did the `,size_t` get in there? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: _"that's what the teacher put there and said to keep"_ Then he probably expects you to use those variables, rather than `ARR_SIZE`. But it's a bit strange since the value is assuredly the same, so in reality we would probably not declare those variables at all.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler pointed you to the obvious errors:

- `arr[i, size_t]` should be `arr[i]`.
- The first function loops `ARR_SIZE` times instead of using the `size` argument.
- The second function loops `ARR_SIZE` times instead of using the `size` variable.
- The third function loops `ARR_SIZE` times also, instead of using `size` computed as `vec.size()`.

All three functions might produce the correct sum, but only by coincidence.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int sum_up(int arr[], size_t size) { //Function to sum up a C-style array
    int sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sum += arr[i];
    return sum;
}

int sum_up(array<int, ARR_SIZE> arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0, size = arr.size(); i < size; i++)
        sum += arr[i];
    return sum;
}

int sum_up(vector<int> vec) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0, size = vec.size(); i < size; i++)
        sum += vec[i];
    return sum;
}
```